# jquery preventDefault() not working properly

Tags: jquery, wordpress, submit, updates, preventdefault

I have this form and a javascript to do the fallowing: I need a user to submit an email address and after that the website should redirect him to another page.

The issue is that event though my script seems to look correct when hitting submit, the page submits and sends a GET request to the server.

The code:

```
<form id="website">
    <div id="new_website">
        <div class="close_new_website"></div>
        <div class="websitemail"><input type="text" name="webmail" /></div>
        <div class="websitesubmit"><input type="submit" class="sendmail" value="Trimite" /></div>
        <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $("#website").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',           
                    async: false,
                    url: 'http://www.website.com/mailer/new_website.php',
                    data: $("#website").serialize(), 
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        //self.location="http://www.website.com/contest/";
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        console.log (data);     
                    }                    
                });
                return false;
            });    
            $(".close_new_website").click(function(){
              $("#new_website").fadeOut();
            });

        });
        </script>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have looked through a lot of issues like this on the website so I do not want to waste your time.

Thank you.

**EDIT 1:**

I have added this `console.log ('loaded');` right after the `$(document).ready( function () {` and it does not fire at all so I thought there should be a problem with Jquery therefore I added in front of everything this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And it is still not working.

*I suppose the problem comes from the last Wordpress Update* or something since yesterday `jquery.min.map` was not found. I downloaded it and added it to its respective loading folder but still the problem persists.

**EDIT 2:**

I tried to replace Jquery 1.10.2 with 1.9.1 and 1.8.3 but still the same happens.

Comment: remove `return false` and see

Comment: Your code should work as i see it

Comment: Check to see if there are any other JS errors on the page. Return FALSE should not cause it to not work.

Comment: tried already. I have moved it in the success / error functions but it did not work either

Comment: @EricL ya, it should just make it not propagate too

Comment: BTW : `data` is not defined within the error callback

Comment: Enable persisting option of the browser's console and check the errors after submission.

Comment: @mugur Your code works for valid HTML. So, have you got more than one element with ID `website` ? Are you unbinding submit handler somewhere else? What about providing a jsfiddle which reproduces your issue?!

Comment: Did you try placing the script in the head and not inside the form, and did you include jQuery, did you validate your markup etc.

Comment: @adeneo I have checked jquery and yes I have checked also the markup. I use php designer to write code and also the firebug did not spit out nay error

Comment: @A.Wolff - I have renamed it several times so it is not a duplicate ID. I will try a fiddle, however I do not know if there might be some conflict around some other components

Comment: @mugur Have you enabled the `persist` option of the firebug for checking the errors?

Comment: Could you try to remove the ready handler as it is anyway useless here. BTW, could you check if handler  is unbound: `$(window).on('load',function(){$.data($("#website")[0],'events').submit});`

Comment: The code works stand-alone in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/drR6P/ so the problem is likely elsewhere on the page (JS error or some other clash). Fiddler 2 shows no postback from the submit.

Comment: @undefined I have ... in my console it is called "Preserve log upon navigation" and I have enabled it but it says nothing about this, only this: a font/woff error, a 404 not found for some image and jquery-1.10.2.min.map

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Here is a fiddle with actual submit script http://jsfiddle.net/nZ2cd/. It send the mail from jsfiddle

Comment: @A.Wolff I have tried already without ready and still it is not working. The code you provided pops out this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

Comment: that suggests that element $('#website') is not found. Could you confirm than: `console.log($('#website').length);` returns 0 and not 1 as expected?

Comment: @A.Wolff I have put that into a ready statement and it does not fire at all. Also tried to put this console.log ('loaded'); right after the ready statement and it does not fire. It looks like the jquery is broken or something.